# Object.toString() OutOfMemory - How to split if it contains Base64?

Tags: java, android, json, string, out-of-memory

I have a response from a web server which contains the whole Base64 content of a pdf (**I CANNOT CHANGE SERVER RESPONSE**). Dimension of this file is over 50MB.

So, when i try to process this response with an AsynkTask the application runs into OOM exception.

```
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {
        String response = null;
        try {
            CommandCode = params[0].toString();
            App application = (App) params[1];
            String data = params[2].toString();  <--- Exception here
            if (application != null) {
                switch (CommandCode) {
                    //STORE ATTACHMENT
                    case Constants.ParserCommand.STORE_ATTACHMENT: {
                        try {
                            if (JSONParser.ParseGetAttachment(new JSONObject(data), application)) {
                                response = "attachment stored";
                            } else {
                                response = null;
                            }
                        } catch (Exception ex) {
                            response = null;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            // some code
        }
    }
```

"Data" is a JSONObject which contains various informations including the base64 content. Above code is called by this few lines:

```
// GET_ATTACHMENT_BY_ATID
JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(_response).getJSONObject("DATA").getJSONObject("Attachment");

task.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, Constants.ParserCommand.STORE_ATTACHMENT, appCDA, jo);
```

All data are needed to create a new record into internal DB to store the document, but the content is stored into a File in filesystem.

My first thought is to isolate the content and work with it. Is there a way to do that? For example:

```
// All data withouth base64Content
JSONObject mainInfo = new JSONObject(_response).getJSONObject("DATA").getJSONObject("Attachment").without("Base64Content");

// Content isolated
String contentInfo = new JSONObject(_response).getJSONObject("DATA").getJSONObject("Attachment").getString("Base64Content");
```

Now the OOM exception still raise. Is there a way to split this base64 content in multiple parts and save them into the file above mentioned by appending?

Comment: you have to change your server json response so that it passes url to your pdf instead of whole base64 encoded content

Comment: I said I cannot change the response

Comment: so you have to write your custom json parser

Comment: Is it possible to make your method receive an InputStream connected to  the server response so you do not have to load all the data in memory at once?

Comment: Check the class of `params[2]`; `if (params[2] instanceof byte[]) {` should do.

Answer (score -1):

```
        Using s As FileStream = File.Open("C:\FilePath\File", FileMode.Open)
            Using sr As New StreamReader(s)
                Using reader As New JsonTextReader(sr)
                    While reader.Read()
                       //Perform your action here
                    End While
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
```

Here you can use FileStream to read the JSON file, it will only load apart of file in memory at a time and not the whole file. The code is in VB, you can implement it in Java in some way.